# Correctly parse function's return statements in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, user-defined-functions

I have a function that can return true; return 'empty'; return 'only_site'; and return 'only_user';

So there are 4 possible returns. In this statement:

```
if(parse_ratings($user_rating, $st_rating, $rating_id) === 'empty') 
{
     $errors[] = 'Neither user_rating, nor site_rating cpule be spidered.'; 
}

     elseif(parse_ratings($user_rating, $st_rating, $rating_id) === 'only_site')           
         $errors[] = 'Only site rating was spidered';

 elseif(parse_ratings($user_rating, $st_rating, $rating_id) === 'only_user')      
         $errors[] = 'Only user rating was spidered';
```

Does the if() remember the output of a function the first time it ran it, or does it run every time there is an if();

Suppose, the script parses through the function and the first IF statement is negative; does it then run the function again to see if the second IF is also negative, or does it remember the return the first time it ran.

I'd like to know this, because I expect it to be true most the time, and don't want the function to be called 4 times in a row.

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: It runs every time. PHP doesn't "know" what your function is doing, and as a result, can't determine if it is cacheable or not - that's your job. Save the result in a variable first.

Comment: Okay, that answered my question. Thanks

Comment: Indenting your code will make it more readable for you and for us, you know.

Comment: I'd mark your answer, but it's a comment, so I can't.

Comment: @Mido, it's indented. All 3 lines are on the same "dent-level"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code inside the `if()` statements will execute each time, the only way to make PHP 'remember' the value is to use a variable:

```
$rating = parse_ratings($user_rating, $st_rating, $rating_id);
if($rating === 'empty') {
    $errors[] = 'Neither user_rating, nor site_rating cpule be spidered.'; 
} elseif($rating === 'only_site') {
    $errors[] = 'Only site rating was spidered';
} elseif($rating === 'only_user') }
    $errors[] = 'Only user rating was spidered';
}
```

Alternatively you can use a [`switch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch(parse_ratings($user_rating, $st_rating, $rating_id)) {
    case 'emtpy':
        $errors[] = 'Neither user_rating, nor site_rating cpule be spidered.'; 
        break;
    case 'only_site':
        $errors[] = 'Only site rating was spidered';
        break;
    case 'only_user':
        $errors[] = 'Only user rating was spidered';
        break;
    case true:
        break;
    default:
        $errors[] = 'An unhandle value was returned';
        break;
}
```